# install LIBEVENT&LIBOPENAL

Tags: software-installation

I wish install one game in Raspberry Pi 2. 
This game has been developper to ubuntu; fedora; windows; mac; ios; android.

Since the raspberry pi 2 is linux too I think they are the "same"

```
>          -Extract the 7zip archive
>          -Open a terminal and run the following commands. You only need to do this once. 
>           $ sudo apt-get install libevent-pthreads-2.0.5 
>           $ sudo apt-get install libopenal1
>          -Start the app by double clicking on
```

it's possible to install this in raspberry pi 2?

Comment: Which game? Also, not all linux based systems are the same. Android in particular has been modified a lot and uses a quite a different set of programs to 'normal' desktop/server linux distros.

Comment: @Wilf the game is YGOpro. You can download at ygopro.co

Comment: Do already have a Raspberry Pi ?

Comment: @flakeshake yes I have. the Pi 2

Comment: I already install the libs but I double click and nothing happens

Comment: This looks like a closed-source game compiled for x86/x64. **It will never work on a Pi** unless the author can be bothered to release an ARMv7 version.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a closed-source game compiled for x86/x64. **It will never work properly** on a Pi unless the author can be bothered to release an ARMv7 version